# ResultSet not processing sql query that has CASE statement in it

Tags: java, jdbc, case

Getting "invalid Number" exception with resultSet executing the SQL query with CASE statement in it.And the same is working fine with out CASE statement.
Although both queries are running good when I run it in SQL developer console.
Is this something not achievable with PreparedStatement?
*java Code:*

```
public Optional<List<ServicesExtn>> fetchThreadUtilByRange(long cohClusterId, String serviceName, LocalDateTime lowTime, LocalDateTime highTime) {
List<ServicesExtn> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
ResultSet resultSet = null;
try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.datasource.getConnection().prepareStatement(DatabaseQueriesEnum.MY_TESTING_QUERY.getQuery())) {    
preparedStatement.setLong(1, cohClusterId);
preparedStatement.setString(2, serviceName);
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(3, Timestamp.valueOf(lowTime));
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, Timestamp.valueOf(highTime));
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
while (resultSet.next()) {
ServicesExtn servicesExtn = new ServicesExtn();
servicesExtn.setServiceName(resultSet.getString("ServiceName"));    
servicesExtn.setRecordTime(resultSet.getTimestamp("RecordTime").toLocalDateTime());
servicesExtn.setTaskBacklog(resultSet.getFloat("FinalPercentage"));
```

*SQL Query:*

```
SELECT temp.Coh_Cluster_Id,
temp.ServiceName AS ServiceName,
node.MemberName,
temp.recordtime      AS RecordTime,
temp.THREADCOUNT     AS THREADCOUNT,
temp.THREADIDLECOUNT AS THREADIDLECOUNT,
CASE
WHEN temp.THREADCOUNT > 0
THEN ((THREADCOUNT-THREADIDLECOUNT) * 100.00) / THREADCOUNT
ELSE                   -1.00
END AS FinalPercentage
FROM NODE_TABLE node,
(SELECT service.Coh_Cluster_Id,
 service.ServiceName,
 service.NodeId,
 service.recordtime,
 service.THREADCOUNT,
 service.THREADIDLECOUNT
FROM CACHE_TABLE cache
RIGHT OUTER JOIN SERVICE_TABLE service
ON cache.Coh_Cluster_Id    = service.Coh_Cluster_Id
AND cache.ServiceName      = service.ServiceName
AND cache.recordtime       = service.recordtime
WHERE service.ServiceName  = ?
AND service.coh_cluster_id = ?
) temp
WHERE node.Coh_Cluster_Id = temp.Coh_Cluster_Id
AND node.ClusterMemberId  = temp.NodeId
AND temp.recordtime       = node.recordtime
AND temp.RECORDTIME BETWEEN ? AND ?
ORDER BY temp.recordtime ASC
```

*Error Stack Trace:*

```
com.wellsfargo.ec.util.NonFatalException: Error getting ThreadUtilPercentage details for chart ORA-01722: invalid number

at com.wellsfargo.ec.dao.CoherenceServicesDAO.fetchThreadUtilByRange(CoherenceServicesDAO.java:324)
at com.wellsfargo.ec.dao.CoherenceServicesDAOTest.testFetchThreadUtilByRange(CoherenceServicesDAOTest.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:886)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1495)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:83)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:83)
at com.wellsfargo.ec.dao.CoherenceServicesDAO.fetchThreadUtilByRange(CoherenceServicesDAO.java:302)
... 25 more
```

Comment: try using  temp.ServiceName as ServiceName in your query.

Comment: Can you post the exact `PreparedStatement` so that we can see. A common mistake is made when concatenating strings, for example `"case" + "when ..."`. You need to add spaces.

Comment: what is the error, how your query look like? what type of your attribute all this should include in your question

Comment: @A2H Please see the edit and stack trace.

Comment: I think @A2H meant could you paste the source code (including the query) of DatabaseQueriesEnum.MY_TESTING_QUERY

Comment: Error Log gives ORA-01722 which means somewhere in the code you are passing String for Numeric value or Check the character strings in the function or expression. Also, check that they contain only numbers, a sign, a decimal point, and the character "E" or "e" and retry the operation.

Comment: @Leozeo - Great pick up.  Yes, the first ? in the query is for ServiceName, but the code has ".setLong(1, cohClusterId)" .... and "setString(2, serviceName);"

Comment: @Leozeo the error occurs at `servicesExtn.setTaskBacklog(resultSet.getFloat("FinalPercentage")`

In Query, `FinalPercentage` will return the % float value. This error code ORA-01722 doesn't make sense to me. Any possible other reason that you might think of?

Comment: @racraman My bad! Thanks for pointing.I have just shuffled the fields for testing. I have corrected the code. My error still remains the same!

Comment: @MadhuStv ORA-01722 means it is a data issue. You are either passing String for Numeric in prepared statement or using it in expression or arithmetic function. In simple words, query expects Integer but receiving String. Just print the values before executing query and substitute every ? with corresponding value and try.

Comment: @MadhuStv I would suggest one more thing, just split your query in multiple parts and execute that will help you in analyzing which part is causing problem.